# EF Core 3.1 выбрать First() из Group

Tags: sql-server, linq, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

Есть удаленный MSSQLServer, на котором есть довольно "тяжелая" View, которую я хочу обработать на стороне сервера БД и не тащить на клиент лишние данные.

Написал запрос, который, по идее, должен вытянуть на клиент только первые значения из каждой группы по полю `TAG_NAME`, каждая группа в свою очередь отсортирована по дате `createDate`:

```
  var tParams = context.TechSet
        .Where(x => x.createDate < endDate && x.createDate > startDate)
        .OrderByDescending(d => d.createDate)
        .GroupBy(x=>x.TAG_NAME)
        .Select(z=>z.First())
        .ToList();
```

Получаю длинный Exception, основная суть которого следующая:

```
   ...First()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList()...
```

Как правильно написать запрос, чтобы он смог корректно транслироваться в SQL ?

Comment: Вы можете попробовать создать хранимую процедуру на стороне SQL Server. Убедитесь, что она работает. Настроить ее на скорость и т.д. После этого просто вызовите хранимую процедуру со стороны клиента.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, я бы с радостью, но не имею доступа к данному SQL Server-у, мне предоставили только View. Поэтому приходится искать обходные пути.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После некоторого изучения форумов пришел к выводу, что разработчики EFCore 3.0/3.1  [перепроектировали LINQ провайдер](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/) и на дату задания вопроса данный фреймворк не умеет транслировать `GroupBy` на сторону SQL. Это весьма не очевидный факт и возможно этот оператор когда-то войдет в список транслируемых.

Также удалось найти решение, которое можно применить к моей ситуации. Основано на применении подзапроса `IQueryable<T>`:

```
var subquery = context.TechSet.Select(x => new { Key = x.TAG_NAME, Tech = x });

var parameters = 
subquery.Select(x => x.Key).Distinct().SelectMany(key => 
                            subquery.Where(e => e.Key == key)
                              .Select(e => e.Tech)
                              .Where(t => t.createDate < endDate && t.createDate > startDate)
                              .OrderByDescending(m => m.createDate)
                              .Take(1)).ToList();
```

Даже при использовании подзапроса скорость выполнения выросла в 4 раза по сравнению с `Where` на стороне БД и (`GroupBy()` + `First()`) на стороне клиента.

Comment: Хороший ответ, +1 с моей стороны!

Comment: Да с группировкой в EF до сих пор туго. Но я бы хотел заметить что данный запрос просто невозможно построить эффективно через группировку, из-за ограничения SQL. Тут нужны оконные функции,